# WPF: window.ShowDialog() then window.Show() - application stopped

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to show the authentication window, then open the main window, 
but when you close the authorization window, application is stopped

```
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  new LoginWindow().ShowDialog();
  new MainWindow().Show();
  // Then application stopped
}
```

BUT!

If the display window authentication by using method Show(), the application does not close after closing the authorization window

```
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  new LoginWindow().Show();
  new MainWindow().Show();
  // Then application running
}
```

Why is this behavior???

Comment: do you have a StartupUri in your App.xaml ?

Comment: Set `Application.ShutDownMode = ShutDownMode.OnMainWindowClose` or explicit.

Comment: My App.xaml<Application x:Class="ClientApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="App_OnStartup">
    <Application.Resources />
</Application>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when the main windows of the application is closed, then the application is closed.

According to the documentation, "Application.MainWindow is automatically set with a reference to the first Window object to be instantiated in the AppDomain."

To get around this, you can try to create first a MainWindow object (without calling Show()),
then create and show the login dialog, and then show the main window.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Eran Otzap!

Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

Is working!

Comment: that wasn't me it was sriram